# crashes after sleep

Tags: mac, crash

in the last few weeks I Have had multiple crashes a day after the Mac goes to sleep.

here is the log

```
zeltak@imbp-50:~|⇒  log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h

Filtering the log data using "composedMessage CONTAINS "Previous shutdown cause""
Skipping info and debug messages, pass --info and/or --debug to include.
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL
2019-12-19 16:35:42.924903-0500 0xbc       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -20
2019-12-19 19:26:36.824995-0500 0x1919     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-19 20:20:46.794533-0500 0x1c80     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-19 20:26:11.649020-0500 0x1ebf     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-19 21:20:20.630227-0500 0x20b2     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-19 22:14:27.574007-0500 0x22a7     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-19 22:19:51.495891-0500 0x22a7     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-19 23:14:00.490561-0500 0x22a7     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-20 00:08:06.470641-0500 0x282e     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-20 01:02:15.395498-0500 0x282e     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-20 01:56:25.387258-0500 0x2c8f     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-20 02:50:35.362751-0500 0x2e80     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-20 03:44:46.298714-0500 0x334b     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-20 04:37:41.253859-0500 0x34e5     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
2019-12-20 07:00:04.159349-0500 0x3502     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Log      - Default:         15, Info:                0, Debug:             0, Error:          0, Fault:          0
Activity - Create:           0, Transition:          0, Actions:           0
ze
```

im using a 2018 MBP, with latest Catalina 10.15.3

in new to the Mac, can anyone help me decipher the log?

Comment: Was this a kernel panic? If yes, can you share a panic string? Also, you are on 10.15.3 beta, right? Did this problem occur with the previous version of the OS / stable release of the OS?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Shutdown 5 is a normal shutdown.

So regarding Shutdown -20,

**Start up in safe mode**

1. Start or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
2. The Apple logo appears on your display.
3. Release the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window.
4. If your startup disk is encrypted with FileVault, you might be asked to log in twice: once to unlock the startup disk, and again to log in to the Finder.
5. To leave safe mode, restart your Mac without pressing any keys during startup.

Check after this whether the issue persists or not. If not, then do the following step:

**Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**

Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd>. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.

Test after this.

If this doesn't help then at last try to:

**Reset the SMC on Mac**

First, shut down your Mac and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd> on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. Release all keys. And, Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.